# http home page to https oauth2 call back Url

Tags: http, https, google-oauth

I have http home page which has Google Sign In . However my Google Callback Url is https only. Google is not returning the access token in this case -

How can I get this to work ?

Comment: We need a better explanation of your problem

Comment: Actually what's happening is my parent page is http. And we have set the Oauth2 callback url as https. so when we do a window.open - does not work - is there a different way to invoke this https oauth url from an http page? btnGoogleLoginClick: function () {
            var retryCount = 0;
            var winPopUp = window.open(_url, 'windowname1','left=300, top=250, height=500, width=600');
            var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function () {

Comment: Why would you set your callback to https if your homepage if http?

Comment: because authentication is secure. Home page is just a search page and we have a div that includes google+ sign in button on home page.

Comment: You need to give more detail of what you have done. At the end of the day, all you need to do is make sure that the OAuth callback URL you registered in the Cloud Console matches what your code is actually sending to Google. NB you can register multiple URLs which might help you.

Comment: It sounds like you've misunderstood what the callback URL is. It is *not* the page you want to end up on after sign in (ie. your home page). It *is* a servlet that google will redirect to (step 4 in the flow diagram at https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow).